# Difference between "ADJ enough to VERB" and "so ADJ as to VERB"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, connotation

What's the difference between the two structures:

- ADJ enough to VERB

  1. "he is **fool enough to** pretend like that"
  2. "But was their crime **great enough to** merit a death sentence?"
  3. "Apple offers products are **good enough to** constitute a category of their own"
- so ADJ as to VERB

  1. "he is **so fool as to** pretend like that"
  2. "But was their crime **so great as to** merit a death sentence?"
  3. "Apple offers products are **so good as to** constitute a category of their own"

Are the interchangeable?
If not, how are they different in terms of usage and also connotation?

Comment: Obvious distinction (perhaps, pragmatics): "a crime great enough to merit a death sentence" is a crime just adequate (approaches from below and touches the threshold of qualification); "a crime so great as to merit a death sentence" is a big crime (it's well past the threshold of qualification, beyond doubt). Just the way I look at it. Also, only one of the alternatives will suit each case, so there's no question of interchangeability.

Comment: By the way, the sentence construction seems either incorrect or unidiomatic in all cases: "He is fool**ish** enough to pretend like that," etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my edit I have switched the two number 2's, which you had the wrong way round.

In the case of 2 and 3, they mean virtually the same thing. The ***so good as to*** construction perhaps stresses a thing's 'goodness' or 'greatness', whilst the ***is it good enough to*** seems to me to query its goodness. It is a very fine nuance, but I do think there are circumstances when I would use one rather than the other. They are not 100% synonymous, but perhaps 95% so!

In the case of 1, I don't particularly like the ***so fool as to pretend***. People may use it, and it is arguably standard English, but personally I wouldn't. It is a matter of taste, and since *fool* is a noun, I think I would say ***Is he so much a fool as to pretend that...***; or ***Is he so foolish as to pretend that...***.

Comment: Why that down vote?